# Python Sqlite - How to select where Column1 OR Column2 are equal to value in List?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I have an GUI where the User could select one or many Filter Values for an Sqlite Query.

At the moment i have this query:

```
    sql="SELECT * FROM Product WHERE LatestChanges IS NOT 'Deleted' AND SubCategory IN ({seq})".format(seq=','.join(['?']*len(self.FilterValues)))
```

Now i want to select from Product where SubCategory OR Category are equal to one on my filter values. How do i do that?

And how do i prevent double selections ?

Comment: You simply add an `OR` condition to the WHERE clause.  You build the logical condition just like you would in every other language, using parenthesis to group compound conditions, etc.  It looks like you already understand how to construct conditional logic, so this seems rather simple.  Am I missing some complexity?

Comment: A question about "double selection" requires more details about your schema and example of the data.  Otherwise it is just guess work as to what would be duplicated and/or how to prevent that.  A WHERE condition alone will not double select anything.  If one row matches both conditions of an OR statement, then the overall condition is simply TRUE.  SELECT does not return a row for each part of a WHERE condition.  Either the entire WHERE condition is TRUE or FALSE, not TRUE multiple times.  Double results occur when you use JOINs or SELECT limited fields that can be duplicate, but you select *.

Comment: I got the basics, but as beeing relatively new to SQL i am kind of stucked sometimes! Thanks for your explanations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the pattern you need to match your existing condition:

```
x AND (y or z)
```

There is no way to compare two things to the same manual list of values in a basic conditional expression -- the list needs to be specified twice.  So if `y` is like `SubCategory IN ({seq})` then `z` needs to be `Category IN ({seq})` so that the list is inserted twice into the string.  Using the named format parameter will at least allow you to reuse the list string, but that's a python feature not an sqlite SQL feature.

---

There is another SQL approach, but it is probably only useful (i.e. more efficient?) if the list is very long.  Otherwise, the above is likely the easiest approach.

You could specify a named CTE (Common Table Expression) defined by a literal column of data, then refer to the same list.  (I split the string into separate lines below for readability, but it is not formatted properly for python):

```
sql="
WITH categoryList AS (
     SELECT * FROM ( VALUES ({seq}))
     )
SELECT * 
FROM Product 
WHERE LatestChanges IS NOT 'Deleted'
    AND (SubCategory IN categoryList OR Category IN categoryList)
".format(seq='),('.join(['?']*len(self.FilterValues)))
```

Notice the delimiter `'),('` is necessary to create a single column of literal values.  Otherwise only a comma delimiter would be interpreted as multiple values in the same row.